# Power BI Waterfall Chart Issue

Tags: sql, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource, powerbi-custom-visuals

Is there any way we can disable the change over period value in waterfall chart.
I am not able to view the total value. Its showing the difference between the total and previous year. But i want to see the total of current year.

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the column charts instaed. That's what they are made for.

Comment: But i need to add a breakdown feature as well.
Hence i opted waterfall.
Any suggestion

Comment: Create a running total quick measure and add it to the tooltips.